# python recurcive os.path append with some brake

Tags: python, recursion, operating-system, file-manager

*Hey, this is my first post (!)
Just looking after headache recursive solution to my littel project :)*

Trying to collect all folders path (recursively),
thats contaion some specefic file
to array of path's.

**ex:**
my (root) path is:

> c:/test

folder test is contain the file 'test.txt' 
and some folders: '1','2','3'.
any of them contain 'test.txt' too!
(if 'text.txt' is not found: 
just brake the loop and dont search in subfolders!)

now my function will look for 'test.txt'
and then, collect all folders to my folderslist:

```
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, 'test.txt')):
full_list = os.listdir(path)
        folderslist = []
        for folder in full_list:
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, folder)) == 0:
                folderslist.append(os.path.join(path, folder))
```

its working not bad, just not recurcive... 
really dont know how to call the function again
with the same list, and force him to change the 'current path'...
not sure if 'list' is the best data struct for me to call with it again.

my goal is to make some opration's in every forlder on this list:

> c:/test c:/test/1 c:/test/2 c:/test/3

but if there is more folders (that not contain 'test.txt' so, just dont add it to my folder list, and do not looking inside)

hope my fisrt post was clear enough :X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.walk` to traverse the subfolders, and if `test.txt` is not found, clear the directory list so `os.walk` won't traverse its subfolders any further:

```
import os
folderslist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('c:/test'):
    if 'test.txt' in files:
        folderslist.append(root)
    else:
        dirs.clear()
```

Comment: thanks its really easy solution for me,
but there is one problem with glob recursive & os.walk:

them to just step inside anyway, 
i must to step inside three only if test.txt is found.

ex:
we got this inside:
`c:\test\test.txt
c:\test\1\test.txt
c:\test\2\a\test.txt
c:\test\3\test.txt
c:\test\3\a\test.txt`

folderslist output must be:
<code>c:\test\test.txt
c:\test\1\test.txt
c:\test\3\test.txt
c:\test\3\a\test.txt</code>

without c:\test\2\a\test.txt cause the 'flow' is cuted...
its must to be like this, cause we dont want to use recursive step ot folder like 'c:\'.

Comment: I see. I'll work on a different solution. Meanwhile, please update your question with this detailed explanation. It was not clear otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: I just updated my answer with your desired logic. Please try again.

Comment: working :)
clearing the directory list is just did the trick so nice ! 
i'll try to make clear myself on top. thanks a lot!!!